# Words or idioms to describe burden of knowledge but not doing or caring about it

Tags: expressions, idioms, american-english

I want to capture the pain which comes from having knowledge that will improve the situation or make the world a better place but being apathetic towards it.

They care, but not enough.  They can act but choose not to

Comment: Interesting question, but please add a sample sentence in which you would use the term you are looking for.

Comment: I don't see how "not caring" or "apathetic" equate to "pain" or "burden".

Comment: There are terms like armchair liberal, hypocrite, or *Tzaddik in pelts* (Yiddish for 'a saint in fur').

Comment: They used to say *talk is cheap*, but these days it's increasingly a matter of ***caring** is cheap*, now the Internet has made it so easy to post or find & upvote indignant tweets about perceived "injustices" everywhere.

Comment: Basically, I agree with @WeatherVane that the actions and emotions involved here aren't really "compatible" (if the primary reason for not *acting* to resolve a problem is "apathy" rather than "practical constraints", I suggest that means you don't *really* care in the first place). But maybe you could describe such a person as ***conflicted*** (or *inconsistent, contradictory,...*).